# Green pixel on the exact left half of my monitor

Tags: display, pixels

The exact left half of my monitor has green pixels as you can see in the following image

[image]

I downloaded a black background just so you can see it better, because i can still use the monitor with no problems, since the problem seems to be worse on darker colors (black in this case). The right half is completely fine.

I tried to adjust and disconnect the cables (except the power), so i don't think it's a PC problem at all since the green pixels remain when all cables are disconnected from the PC.

Is there anything else i can do? The monitor is less than 2yo and i haven't even transported it elsewhere for over a year, let alone damaging it...

Comment: How is it connected? What's the display resolution? I'd suspect a dual DVI issue, but we can eliminate that quickly if you connect HDMI, DP or VGA. Also test this doesn't appear in a screenshot, only on the screen itself.

Comment: It's currently connected with a DP cable on 1920x1080 resolution. I will try to take a screenshot later when i'm home but i suspect it's a panel problem... Thank you!

Comment: Welcome. Yup 1080p over DP would eliminate the dual-channel possibility entirely. TOOGAM's answer is certainly pointing in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

Check the monitor's warranty.

This certainly doesn't appear to be caused by software running on the computer.  An issue with the cables seems unlikely.  So it is likely an issue with the monitor.  Some devices may have "user serviceable" parts, like having a battery be replaced.  For a monitor, the main user serviceable actions would be to check the cables, and interacting with any built-in menu options (if such a thing exists).  For instance, if there is a "factory reset" option that you can manage to access and use.

I recall working in an IT company once and we ended up selling some cheap monitors that later turned out to not work so well.  The manufacturer directed us to some sort of reset procedure that involved holding down some buttons for a while when turning the monitor back on.  Since this monitor is made by NEC, NEC would be the company that could supply you with information about such a technique if such a thing exists.

Otherwise, there probably isn't much more you can do to service it, except to get it replaced.  If the device is still under warranty, that might end up being only inconvenient, rather than also needing to be notably expensive.  Communication with the manufacturer can let you know available options.  (Such options could possibly include shipping the monitor to them, or having you drive it to a local store that the manufacturer has some sort of agreement with.)

Comment: Thank you! I would like to avoid having my monitor replaced since that means I'm left with no monitor to work on my daily basis. However, the monitor is still under warranty so that seems to be the best and only solution at the moment, unfortunately...

Comment: Check how your supplier deals with warranty returns - some are great, some… not so much. I had a Dell display fail in warranty. they sent a new one & simultaneously collected the old one, so my downtime was pretty much how long it took me to box one & unbox the other.

Comment: Ok, I will try and suggest exactly that. It would be a great help!